# CSS - Two Non-Scrolling Columns with a scrolling content pane

Tags: css

I have a situation where I have designed a three column layout, and it is working fine. However I was asked to make it to where the two menu panes (the left and center) are "fixed" and do not scroll with the rest of the content.

I have been struggling for a bit with this; Simply making them have `position: fixed` does not work, it throws off the entire design and the height of the columns. I am starting to think this is not possible to perform on my specific layout, but I thought I would ask smarter people for some assistance.

I am posting my code, as well as a link to a jsFiddle.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/96kv5/)

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
        <div>menu items</div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <h3>sub menu items</h3>
        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <header>content header</header>
        <article>content body</article>
    </div>
</div>

#top {
    background-color: #25282b;
    height: 64px;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#left, #center, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0px;
}
#left {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(38, 46, 51, 1);
    color: #7d8285;
}
#left div:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#center {
    width: 228px;
    background-color: rgba(57, 65, 71, 1);
    color: #999ea1;
}
#center div:first-child {
    padding: 15px;
}
#center div:first-child h3 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#right {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    vertical-align: top;
}
#right header {
    background-color: #3e7aa5;
    height: 32px;
}
#right article {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any columns that scroll... Please provide more information as to what you're talking about and also mention which columns you don't want to scroll ^_^ We need more info

Comment: I am so sorry, I have updated the fiddle. I want the entire column where the large blocks of lorum ipsum content to scroll, while the rest of the page stays still.

Comment: Do you want the header (`#top`) to always be visible or to have the behavior it currently has?

Comment: I would like it to remain visible if that is at all possible, though I realize it may not be.

Comment: If you don't mind using `calc`, you could [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/96kv5/3/)